# Assigning null value to a numeric column while importing csv

Tags: postgresql

I am using the next cmd to import a csv file to my PostgreSQL table:

```
\copy myTable from 'myTable_sample_nh.csv' with delimiter E'\t' null as '\x00';
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""
CONTEXT:  COPY myTable, line 1, column salary: ""
```

How can I do to bypass this error? I mean, during an INSERT row operation, if I do not specify a column then the DB does not assign a value to that column. In this case, the CSV file does not have a value for a numeric column field so the intention is to assign no value to that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'\x00'` does not mean a zero byte, it means backslash followed by `x` followed by 
`00`.

Considering that, it actually works:

```
create table test(n numeric);

\copy test from stdin with delimiter E'\t' null as '\x00'
>> \x00
>> \.

test=> select n is null from test;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

But presumably what you meant is a null byte to represent a SQL NULL. Syntactically, it can be written as `E'\x00'` but in practice it's unusable:  for implementation reasons, null bytes in strings are not supported by Postgres, in pretty much any context. In the context of the null specification of `\copy` it would be rejected even before submitting input data:

```
\copy test from stdin with delimiter E'\t' null as E'\x00'
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
```

The solution is to use something else that doesn't appear in the data, or the empty string: `null as ''` is accepted by \copy.